# How to execute "completable" in parallel with a "single" without waiting for the "completable" to complete?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive

My function has to do some work (completable, "countMetrics()") in parallel with another work (single, "fetchMessagesFromStorage()").

"fetchMessagesFromStorage" returns messages that I need to pass back to the caller.

"countMetrics" has no return value, it just updates some metrics, I don't care about the result of it wether it is the success or fail.

I tried to do this:

```
private Single<Response> fetchMessages(Parameters params) {
   countMetrics().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe() // Schedulers.io(), Schedulers.computation() don't work either
   return fetchMessagesFromStorage(params)
}
```

But "countMetrics" is still executing in the same thread and blocks until finished, only then "fetchMessagesFromStorage" takes it's turn to execute.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want to run `countMetrics` as soon as `fetchMessages` method is called? You should wrap everything inside `fetchMessages` into a `Single.defer`  if you want `countMetrics` to only run when the Single returned by `fetchMessages` is subscribed to

Comment: @Gustavo I want countMetrics to start together with fetchMessagesFromStorage (in parallel)